# how to change color of linear progress bar in materializecss?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using materialize css. Can you guys tell me how to change the color of 
the linear Preloader?

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the color to blue.

Comment: you can follow this  https://codepen.io/holdencreative/pen/pvxGxy?editors=1100

Comment: Hi @kalidasrajeev if it helps you can mark as accepted

Answer (score 5):

I took a look inside the sass files for the framework and you actually need to target:

```
.progress {
    background-color: darkblue;
}


.progress .indeterminate {
    background-color: steelblue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/BaNVOBQ

Answer (score 2):

Try this i think it's helpful to you..

**html**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* Progress Bar */
.progress {
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #acece6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  overflow: hidden; }

  .progress .indeterminate {
    background-color: red; }
    .progress .indeterminate:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: inherit;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      will-change: left, right;
      -webkit-animation: indeterminate 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.815, 0.735, 0.395) infinite;
              animation: indeterminate 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.815, 0.735, 0.395) infinite; }
    .progress .indeterminate:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: inherit;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      will-change: left, right;
      -webkit-animation: indeterminate-short 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) infinite;
              animation: indeterminate-short 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) infinite;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.15s;
              animation-delay: 1.15s; }

@-webkit-keyframes indeterminate {
  0% {
    left: -35%;
    right: 100%; }
  60% {
    left: 100%;
    right: -90%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    right: -90%; } }
@keyframes indeterminate {
  0% {
    left: -35%;
    right: 100%; }
  60% {
    left: 100%;
    right: -90%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    right: -90%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes indeterminate-short {
  0% {
    left: -200%;
    right: 100%; }
  60% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%; }
  100% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%; } }
@keyframes indeterminate-short {
  0% {
    left: -200%;
    right: 100%; }
  60% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%; }
  100% {
    left: 107%;
    right: -8%; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
</div>
```

Add `background-color` to both classes `progress` and `indeterminate`

```
.progress{
    background-color: blue;
}
.indeterminate{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Simply use materialize color classes.

```
<div class="progress blue">
    <div class="indeterminate yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.progress{
      margin-top:50%;
      background-color:gray;
}
.progress .indeterminate {

    background-color: orange;
}
```

You just need to change these two css only.